# Can 2 of the same Pokemon with the same CP have different stats?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was recently talking with my friend about leveling up Pokemon in Pokemon Go. We weren't exactly sure how Stats work in this game, or other Pokemon games for that matter, but we are curious if the main thing we should look at is CP, or if there are other stats that we should look at, that say could make a CP 150 more powerful than a CP 160 Pokemon?

How should we go about determining which Pokemon is stronger when we have duplicates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes! Combat Power (CP) is calculated from three different stats: attack, defense and stamina. Some people call these IV (Individual Values).

Someone from The Silph Road has made an IV calculator that calculates these values from the values you can see in the game:
https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4tkk75/updated_iv_calculator_automatically_calculate_ivs/

Comment: So that means that on most of the time, a higher CP pokemon will have better stats than a lower CP pokemon, as CP is a combination of all 3 stats?

Comment: Yes. A Pokémon with a higher Combat Power will have better stats overall. A Pokémon with a slightly lower Combat Power may have better values in one of the stats, while the other stats will be lower. In summary, higher CP is better in general.