# Is overall power of a Pokemon determined by their CP alone?

Tags: pokemon-go

Let's assume I have 2 Pokemon of the same kind with identical movesets and the only difference is that one has an IV of 100 and the other one has 90.

If I were to upgrade both of their CP to 3000 would they end up "equally strong" or would the 100 IV one be stronger?

Comment: Related: [In Pokemon GO, what are my Pokemon's hidden IV stats, and why do they matter?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/276692/143571), [What is better to have? A pokemon with higher IV but lower CP or vice versa?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/286325/143571), [Can 2 of the same Pokemon with the same CP have different stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/276200/143571). There are tons of questions about CP and stats already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will (slightly) disagree with Markol's answer here.  CP is a computed term based on the IVs (Attack, Defense, and Stamina).  It attempts to show how strong a Pokémon is based on those IVs, but it is biased towards Attack.  (See [PokeAssistant's page on CP for the formula details.](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator?locale=en))

```
(Attack)*(Sqrt(Defense))*(Sqrt(Stamina))*(Level Multiplier)^2 / 10
```

In some cases, overweighting Attack is appropriate - particularly in PVE where you don't care nearly as much how quickly your Pokémon takes damage, you're really in a rush against time to *deal* damage.

However, in PvP, Attack and Defense are both valuable (equally so, for the most part), as well as Stamina.  As such, CP doesn't perfectly reflect the usefulness of a Pokémon.  In PvP, two identical Pokémon CP-wise but not IV wise, the higher IV one may be *worse*, or may be better, depending on the details of the difference.  Two that are the same level but one is higher ATK and one is higher DEF, for example, the higher DEF one is likely better overall for PvP but the higher ATK one is possibly better in PvE (or identical).

Additionally, in PvP the ATK value will determine tiebreakers (currently) for charge move priority - a higher ATK Pokémon will go first, in a mirror match, if both fire off their charge move on the same turn.  (In a non-mirror match, it's unlikely the base stats would be sufficiently similar for IVs to matter.)

All that aside, two points:

1. For the most point, CP is fine, and just use the best CP you can.  In Great or Ultra league, you may lose some very close matches on the margins, but much more important are choosing Pokémon, specific moves, and powering them up to the cap.
2. You don't have to figure out which is better - there are lots of sites that can tell you what the best IV set is for a particular Pokémon in a particular league.  Just search PVP Rankings Pokémon Go, and you'll have numerous results that give you good advice (not all identical - some of this is more subjective, or at least subject to model differences, but most are useful enough.)

Comment: You are right, my answer is quick for general player, yours is for competitive players  thanks for additional info

Comment: If that's the case, do you mind me changing the best answer to his?

Comment: Do you have a source for your formula?

Comment: @Mast https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator?locale=en section "IVs Explained
"

Comment: @Mathias711 Thanks, that's not the page I use normally but it's better explained so I'll use that!

Answer (score 5):

IV corresponds to stat distribution, so I would say, it is already acounted for in CP. The one with 100 IV will have lower lvl to the one with same CP, but lower IV.
TLDR; two Pokémons with same CP are of the same power

Comment: I wouldn't say they are the same power because they could have a different distribution.  I would say something with Max attack might be better then one with max HP.

Comment: I mean power in sense of "overall power" not attack power.

Comment: @Nat I agree with both your comments. CP is gained faster with attack IV, if I am right.

Comment: @Styxsksu So much matters what you're using the Pokémon for - PvE and PvP are such different beasts in terms of ideal Pokémon...